# Add HTML Code to existing HTML file using PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

In my index.html there are several Links and it looks like this

```
 <div id="links">
    <a class="link" href="download1.html" target="_blank">Download 1</a>
    <a class="link" href="download2.html" target="_blank">Download 2</a>
    <a class="link" href="download3.html" target="_blank">Download 3</a>
    <a class="link" href="download4.html" target="_blank">Download 4</a>
</div>
```

and what I want to do is, adding new Links to this div via PHP. I tried something with DOM and appendChild but it isn't working like I want.

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$tabtitle = $_GET['tabtitle'];

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom = loadHTMLFile('index.html');

$node = "<a class="link" href="{$filename}.html" target="_blank">{$tabtitle}</a>";
$findelement = $dom->getElementById('links');
$dom->parentNode->appendChild($findelement, $node);

echo $dom->saveXML();?>
```

I'm already able to create the refering HTML File via PHP but I don't want to add these Links above manually all the time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: _"but it isn't working like I want"_ - So what actually happens? It's easier for us to help you fix problems with your code if we know what those problems are.

Comment: Must this be done on the server-side? How about interjecting PHP within the HTML?

Comment: `$dom->saveXML()`? that is HTML

Comment: What would `$dom->parentNode` actually be??

Comment: `$dom = loadHTMLFile('index.html');` is incorrect - that should be `$dom -> loadHTMLFile('index.html');`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Oh I missed that. This shouldn't be there

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Nothing happens

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius And saveXML was something I saw in another Post  and they used it to save HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there are a few minor errors which, when corrected as below, should yield what I think you are trying to do:

```
<?php

    if( isset(
        $_GET['filename'],
        $_GET['tabtitle']
    )){
        $filename = $_GET['filename'];
        $tabtitle = $_GET['tabtitle'];
        
        
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTMLFile( __DIR__ . '/index.html' );
        
        
        $div=$dom->getElementById('links');
        
        $a=$dom->createElement('a',$tabtitle);
        $a->setAttribute('class','link');
        $a->setAttribute('href',$filename.'.html');
        $a->setAttribute('target','_blank');
        
        $div->appendChild($a);
        
        echo $dom->saveHTML();
    }
?>
```

[image: Example output]

To save the `index.html` file ( for me called `x-index.html` to avoid conflict with existing file )

```
<?php
    
    if( isset(
        $_GET['filename'],
        $_GET['tabtitle']
    )){
        $filename = $_GET['filename'];
        $tabtitle = $_GET['tabtitle'];
        
        
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTMLFile( __DIR__ . '/x-index.html' );
        
        
        $div=$dom->getElementById('links');
        
        $a=$dom->createElement('a',$tabtitle);
        $a->setAttribute('class','link');
        $a->setAttribute('href',$filename.'.html');
        $a->setAttribute('target','_blank');
        
        $div->appendChild($a);
        
        echo $dom->saveHTML(); //display
        
        
        $dom->saveHTMLFile( __DIR__ . '/x-index.html' ); //save
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it in general it's doing what it should do. Now the problems are: When I do it with an external PHP file, it doesn't save the changes to the Index.html

Comment: And the second problem is, when I rename my index.html to index.php and implement your code to the index file, it doesn't save either so after I visit the Index file after adding new Link, it's not updated

Comment: No - the code you posted and I tweaked will not save the external file. Rather than `echo $dom->saveHTML()` you need to `saveHTMLFile()`

Comment: So `echo $dom->saveHTMLFile()` ? If so, it didn't work. It doesn't give errors

Comment: One last question: If I run this PHP script, it mess up the Layout of my HTML File, how can I avoid this?

Comment: In what way does it `"mess up the Layout of my HTML File"`?

Comment: Sorry layout was the wrong word for it, I mean it mess up the file formatting. So for example all tags within the Head tag are on the same line.

Comment: take a look at the PHP manual regarding properties of DOMDocument - especially the `formatOutput`